what is the key code value for speaker and amplifier in matrix keyboard?
Can someone point me to the list of key codes that come from getKeyCode() for Amplifier and Speaker which were used in landline phones
example:
7 -->"KEYCODE_0"
8 -->"KEYCODE_1"
I have looked for it surfing in google and I couldn't able to find it anywhere. Is there any keycode value for speaker and amplifier available.
